# What is causing "no such file: mshtmhst.h" using Wails on Windows?

Tags: go

I'm trying to use Wails on a Windows box, but I'm getting:

> In file included from C:\Go\external\pkg\mod\github.com\wailsapp\wails@v1.0.2-pre2\lib\renderer\webview\webview.go:26:0: ./webview.h:64:22: fatal error: mshtmhst.h: No such file or directory

I've tried this on two boxes: one with Windows 10 64 bit and another with Windows 10 32 bit.

My primary development box is Win 10 64 bit, but my final application must be compiled in 32 bit.

Comment: I would venture a guess that what's causing that error is the fact that the file is missing. Did you install the requisite header files, and place them in the proper path for your system configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Flimzy says in his comment, I did a fresh reinstall of my Mingw. It works.